# How to have a sticky footer at the bottom of the page, but do not have it overlap other elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a footer bar that sticks at the bottom of the page, which I currently use "position:fixed" issue is I have a div that I want to take up the whole area above the footer, the problem is though the bottom part of the div gets overlapped due to the position:fixed. When I remove position:fixed, the page requires scrolling.... can anyone give me an example of how to properly create a footer that stays at the bottom of the page without overlapping over elements and creating a scrollbar? I am using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: "Sticky footer" is a classic CSS problem, you can check the follow link for one solution: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `margin-bottom` to the last element before the footer which is at least as large as the footer is high.